# Find a specific item in the list for a variable when list is dinamic

Tags: r, list, organizer

I have multiple values (a list of values) for variable x(i). For example x(1):

```
[1] "$30 1 d"              "$250 2 d"             "$300 3 d"            
 [4] "$100 3 d"             "$10 4 d"              "$30 1 d"             
 [7] "$250 2 d"             "$300 3 d"             "$100 3 d"            
[10] "$10 4 d"              "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Team member"
```

I want to find the word after "organizer" for variable X(1). For instance here is Boyette, FL (The name of city and state after organizer).
Here organizer is the 11th value in the list. Maybe for variable x(2), another output for person 2, the organizer may be located in the 9th value in the list. Could you help me in writing a code in R for solving this issue? I want to find the name of the city and state for each person.

Comment: Try `f1 <- function(x, pat) grep(pat, x, ignore.case = TRUE);f1(df1[[1]], "organizer")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this error: Error in grep(pat, location_m, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
  object 'df1' not found

Comment: The error is: object 'df1' not found. Could you please explain this formula? Could you please let me know the way I can solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks, but The name of the city and state would be different for different x. I have 1300 variables X(1)....x(1300).

Comment: Could you please help me How I can define df1 for different x? because I do not know the values in the list for different x.

Comment: `df1` is the name of your dataset. What did you call it? Now replace `df1` with the name of your dataset

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Ok thanks.  The output for x1 is ``` [1] "$30 1 d"              "$250 2 d"             "$300 3 d"            
 [4] "$100 3 d"             "$10 4 d"              "$30 1 d"             
 [7] "$250 2 d"             "$300 3 d"             "$100 3 d"            
[10] "$10 4 d"              "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Team member"  ```

Comment: But the output for x2 is : ``` [1] "$40"              "$450"             "$130"            
 [4] "$800"             "$98"               "OrganizerMilwaukee, WI"             
 [7]  "$400"        "Clear"                  "$760"

Comment: I want to find the word after organizer for each x for example in x1 is Boyette, FL and in x2 is Milwaukee, WI. I have for example 1000 different X: x1,..., x1000, and I want to find the name of city and state after organizer for each x. The name of the city and state is different for different x and the arrangement in the list is different for different X.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(rebus)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rebus'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stringr':
#> 
#>     regex
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     alpha

#create some data
data <- map(1:5, ~  rep('abcde', .x)) 

for (i in seq_along(data)) {
    data[[i]][[i]] <- 'OrganizerBoyette, FL'
}

data
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "OrganizerBoyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "abcde"                "OrganizerBoyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "abcde"                "abcde"                "OrganizerBoyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "abcde"                "abcde"                "abcde"               
#> [4] "OrganizerBoyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "abcde"                "abcde"                "abcde"               
#> [4] "abcde"                "OrganizerBoyette, FL"

#subsetting Organizer 
map(data, ~ str_subset(.x, pattern = 'Organizer') %>%
        str_match_all('Organizer' %R% capture('.*$'))) %>% flatten() 
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]                   [,2]         
#> [1,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1]                   [,2]         
#> [1,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1]                   [,2]         
#> [1,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>      [,1]                   [,2]         
#> [1,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>      [,1]                   [,2]         
#> [1,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"

map(data, ~ str_subset(.x, pattern = 'Organizer') %>%
        str_match_all('Organizer' %R% capture('.*$'))) %>% flatten() %>%
    reduce(rbind)
#>      [,1]                   [,2]         
#> [1,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> [2,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> [3,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> [4,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
#> [5,] "OrganizerBoyette, FL" "Boyette, FL"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but The name of the city and state would be different for different x. I have 1300 variables X(1),....X(1300). For example, for X1 I want to find "organizerMilwaukee, WI". For x2 I want to find "organizerBoyette , FL". The are located in different arrange. For example for x1, it could be the 5th item in the list but for x2 it could be the 9th item in the list.

Comment: Do you have more information about X? Is it a dataframe or a list? X(1) would be used if X was a function which is not the case here. `class(X)` is for extracting the object class.